# Why use iFrames in a web application?

Tags: web-applications, html5, software-as-a-service

I am new at a company that has a saas web application, which uses iframes to load content from several different servers (all operated by us). Is there any known compelling reasons to use iFrames instead of DOM manipulation?

I've tried searching google, stack overflow and programmers, but most questions and answers seem to be related to content pages, and not software. SEO is not a concern. We have a known user base with specific browser/os requirements.

Comment: I do intend on having this conversation with the people who had influence on developing the system, but I'd like to do some research beforehand.

Comment: Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23178505/good-reasons-why-not-to-use-iframes-in-page-content

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: @Ryan Thanks for the link, a good reference, though slightly different from my question, which is specific to saas web applications, not content pages. There are no issues with SEO, or linking/bookmarking.

Comment: [specific example](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/262694/why-use-iframes-in-a-web-application#comment533600_262694 "check the information suggested in this comment and edit the question to explain what you find missing there, if anything")

Answer (score 4):

It's just easier, and a pragmatic solution. iFrame keeps everything in it's own semi-private window, so there's little risk of CSS or JS conflicts.

Not the greatest for user experience, but simple and effective especially for internal facing apps.

Comment: I feel like iframes elicit an groan of displeasure from devs these days, but you are spot on in that they can isolate functionality without worrying about JS/CSS/AJAX issues.